# Qt set a custom widget inside a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, view, model

I need to put a custom widget inside a `QTableView` cell from a subclassed `QAbstractTableModel`.

I searched for already given solutions but no one catch my needs.
The custom widget must stay here all the time and not only in editing mode like with the `QItemDelegate::createEditor`.
The custom widget may be everything, i'm searching for a general solutions for all the widget not only `QPushButtons` or `QCheckBox`.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: you can implement the method : `paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const` of a custom QStyledItemDelegate

Comment: yes but in this way i can just paint a static widget, i would like to have an interactive one

Comment: Sounds very strange. What is the aim for this?

Comment: I have some widget that are interactive, and i would like to show them inside the table because they interact outside the table

Comment: @lo-re `QTableWidget` (not `QTableView`) provides such functionality but breaks MVC principles (if they are needed in this case). `QGridLayout` can display any widgets in table order. Isn't it enough for you?

Comment: @ilotXXI yes i can use other systems to obtain what i need but i would like to know if there is a way to do it with the model-view system

In internet there are many solutions to different but similar cases so i tried to find a way for my case but i failed, so before quit i asked here

Comment: @ilotXXI I think you mean [`QTableWidget::setCellWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget), which is just a convenience function for [`QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget). The documentation of `setIndexWidget` says it does not support custom dynamic content and that you need `QItemDelegate` for it.

Comment: @m7913d It is a recommendation. I think it is because an inserted widget doesn't interact with real model data without delegate. If we use ugly `QTableWidget` and don't worry about any models, it is ok, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) and overriding [`QAbstractItemView::dataChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#dataChanged) to achieve what you want as follows:

```
class MyTableView : public QTableView
{
protected:
  void dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight, const QVector<int> & roles)
  {
    QPushButton *pPushButton = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(indexWidget(topLeft));
    if (pPushButton)
        pPushButton->setText(model()->data(topLeft, Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
    else
        QTableView::dataChanged(topLeft, bottomRight, roles);
  }
};

void main ()
{
    MyTableView table;
    table.setIndexWidget(table.model()->index(0, 0, QModelIndex()),new QPushButton());
}
```

Note that it is an incomplete implementation, but it should show you how you can solve your problem. A real implementation should update all QPushButton between topLeft and bottomRight.

Comment: so the solution is only to subclass the view instead of the model

Comment: I think subclassing the view is indeed a solution for your problem, but you should try it yourself if it works well for your specific problem. I have no idea why you would subclass the model to solve this problem, because your problem is about the visualisation.

Comment: i opted for subclass the model and paint static "widget", but your answer solved the initial problem so i set to accepted. Thanks

Comment: You may also add your own answer and accept that one, it may be interesting to other users to view the different possibilities.